# Small style adjustments of bibstyle musuos (setting brackets, deleting period)

Tags: biblatex

I wanna set brackets around the series + number. The period before the bracket should be removed, too. I use the bibstyle musuos.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}



\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
    @Collection{Titel2000,
        date      = {2000},
        editor    = {Mustermann, Max},
        title     = {Titel},
        location  = {Ort},
        number    = {1},
        series    = {Reihe},
    }
    @InCollection{Titel2001,
        author    = {Mustermann, Max},
        booktitle = {Buchtitel},
        date      = {2020},
        title     = {Titel},
        editor    = {Bauer, Agathe},
        location  = {Ort},
        number    = {1},
        pages     = {100--200},
        series    = {Reihe},
    }
\end{filecontents}

%Bibliographie
\usepackage [backend=biber, style=musuos, doi=false, isbn=false, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
    \ifinteger{#1}
    {\textsuperscript{#1}}
    {#1\isdot\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{edition}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}
\newcommand{\replaceedition}[1]{%
    \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{edition}%
        \newunit}
    {}%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to patch driver #1}}
}
\replaceedition{book}
\replaceedition{collection}
\replaceedition{inbook}
\replaceedition{incollection}
\replaceedition{manual}

\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{n\adddot d\adddot}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{year}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}

\begin{document}
    Zitat 1\autocite{Titel2000} und Zitat 2\autocite{Titel2001}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We redefine the `series+number` bibmacro to print the brackets, we also instruct it to change the punctuation before the brackets to just a space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=musuos,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=true,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \newunit}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\textsuperscript{#1}}
    {#1\isdot\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
\newcommand{\replaceedition}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {}%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to patch driver #1}}}
\replaceedition{book}
\replaceedition{collection}
\replaceedition{inbook}
\replaceedition{incollection}
\replaceedition{manual}

\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{n\adddot d\adddot}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{year}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@Collection{Titel2000,
  date      = {2000},
  editor    = {Mustermann, Max},
  title     = {Titel},
  location  = {Ort},
  number    = {1},
  series    = {Reihe},
}
@InCollection{Titel2001,
  author    = {Mustermann, Max},
  booktitle = {Buchtitel},
  date      = {2020},
  title     = {Titel},
  editor    = {Bauer, Agathe},
  location  = {Ort},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {100--200},
  series    = {Reihe},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    Zitat 1\autocite{Titel2000} und Zitat 2\autocite{Titel2001}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Max Mustermann (Hrsg.): Titel (Reihe 1). Ort, 2000. 2 Max Mustermann: Titel. In: Buchtitel. Hrsg. von Agathe Bauer (Reihe 1). Ort, 2020, S. 100–200.]